# How to hide 1 column in a row and show second column only from medium screen to small screen in bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

So I am trying to achieve is that I have made a row and inside that row there are two columns first is a left_bar column and second column is large image so what I want is that when the screen hits medium breakpoint from medium to small screen I only have to show the large image i.e column 2 and not column 1 i.e the left_bar 
I have also posting the required output from medium screen to small screen.[image]
I am also mentioning my code snippet

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px){
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 700px){
  
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 900px){


}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 920px){
}
    .left_bar{
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #030C13;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .hero_image{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url('https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        background-position: right;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .img-thumbnail{
        border: none !important;

    } 
    .profile_pic {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-top: 3em;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        box-shadow: -1px 0px 0px 14px #262837
    }
    .name{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 1em;
        color: #FCFEFF;
    }
    .fb_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .tw_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;

    }
    .lg_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .fa-twitter {
        font-size: 20px;
        left: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fa-facebook-f {
        font-size: 20px;
        left: 19px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tw_div:hover{
        background-color: white;
    }
    .tw_div:hover .fa-twitter{
        color:black ;
    }
    .fb_div:hover{
        background-color: white;
    }
    .fb_div:hover .fa-facebook-f{
        color: black;
    }
    .lg_div:hover{
        background-color: white;
    }
    .lg_div:hover .fa-instagram{
        color: black;
    }
    .fa-instagram {
        font-size: 24px;
        left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fa-skype{
        font-size: 24px;
        left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fa-linkedin-in{
        font-size: 24px;
        left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .sky_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .sky_div:hover{
        background-color:white ;
    }
    .sky_div:hover .fa-skype{
        color: black;
    }
    .ld_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .ld_div:hover{
        background-color:white ;
    }
    .ld_div:hover .fa-linkedin-in{
        color: black;
    }
    .nav_tabs{
        display: flex;
    }
    .nav-link{
        color: #92959D ;
        margin-bottom: 1em
    }
    .nav-link:hover{
        color: white;
    }
    .fa-home{
        color: #377DB3;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .fa-user{
        color: #5F656F;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-user{
        color: #377DB3;
    }
    .fa-file{
        color: #5F656F;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-file{
        color: #377DB3;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-list-alt{
        color: #377DB3;
    }
    .fa-list-alt{
        color:#5F656F ;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-server{
        color: #377DB3;
        
    }
    .fa-server{
        color: #5F656F;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-envelope{
        color: #377DB3;
    }
    .fa-envelope{
        color: #5F656F;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-item a{
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assignment 8</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-lg-block col-lg-3 left_bar">
            <img src="https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg" class="img-fluid profile_pic mx-auto" alt="...">
            <h2 class="name">Alex Smith</h2>
            <div class="socials mt-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="tw_div"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></div>
                <div class="fb_div"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></div>
                <div class="lg_div"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></div>
                <div class="sky_div"><i class="fab fa-skype"></i></div>
                <div class="ld_div"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_tabs">
            <ul class="nav flex-column ms-lg-3 mt-lg-4 ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><span class="ms-2">Home</span> </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span class="ms-2">  About</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file"></i><span class="ms-2">  Resume</span>  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i><span class="ms-2">Portfolio</span> </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-server"></i><span class="ms-2">Services</span> </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> <span class="ms-2">Contact</span></a>
                  </li>
                     
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
     <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9  hero_image">

     </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show/hide elements in BS5 you can use **.d-{breakpoint}-{value}** classes.
The classes are applied from min-width: 0; and up.

So, you can set .d-block.d-md-none, which means to show block for mobile, and up to 'md' breakpoint (tablet and larger) - hidden.

And opposite: .d-none.d-md-block - will hide for mobile and show block for tablet and larger

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px){
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 700px){
  
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 900px){


}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 920px){
}
    .left_bar{
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #030C13;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .hero_image{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url('https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        background-position: right;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .img-thumbnail{
        border: none !important;

    } 
    .profile_pic {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-top: 3em;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        box-shadow: -1px 0px 0px 14px #262837
    }
    .name{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 1em;
        color: #FCFEFF;
    }
    .fb_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .tw_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;

    }
    .lg_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .fa-twitter {
        font-size: 20px;
        left: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fa-facebook-f {
        font-size: 20px;
        left: 19px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tw_div:hover{
        background-color: white;
    }
    .tw_div:hover .fa-twitter{
        color:black ;
    }
    .fb_div:hover{
        background-color: white;
    }
    .fb_div:hover .fa-facebook-f{
        color: black;
    }
    .lg_div:hover{
        background-color: white;
    }
    .lg_div:hover .fa-instagram{
        color: black;
    }
    .fa-instagram {
        font-size: 24px;
        left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fa-skype{
        font-size: 24px;
        left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fa-linkedin-in{
        font-size: 24px;
        left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .sky_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .sky_div:hover{
        background-color:white ;
    }
    .sky_div:hover .fa-skype{
        color: black;
    }
    .ld_div{
        position: relative;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #1D212B;
        padding: 1.5em;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .ld_div:hover{
        background-color:white ;
    }
    .ld_div:hover .fa-linkedin-in{
        color: black;
    }
    .nav_tabs{
        display: flex;
    }
    .nav-link{
        color: #92959D ;
        margin-bottom: 1em
    }
    .nav-link:hover{
        color: white;
    }
    .fa-home{
        color: #377DB3;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .fa-user{
        color: #5F656F;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-user{
        color: #377DB3;
    }
    .fa-file{
        color: #5F656F;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-file{
        color: #377DB3;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-list-alt{
        color: #377DB3;
    }
    .fa-list-alt{
        color:#5F656F ;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-server{
        color: #377DB3;
        
    }
    .fa-server{
        color: #5F656F;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-link:hover .fa-envelope{
        color: #377DB3;
    }
    .fa-envelope{
        color: #5F656F;
        font-size:1.5em;
    }
    .nav-item a{
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assignment 8</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-none d-lg-block col-lg-3 left_bar">
            <img src="https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg" class="img-fluid profile_pic mx-auto" alt="...">
            <h2 class="name">Alex Smith</h2>
            <div class="socials mt-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="tw_div"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></div>
                <div class="fb_div"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></div>
                <div class="lg_div"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></div>
                <div class="sky_div"><i class="fab fa-skype"></i></div>
                <div class="ld_div"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_tabs">
            <ul class="nav flex-column ms-lg-3 mt-lg-4 ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><span class="ms-2">Home</span> </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span class="ms-2">  About</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-file"></i><span class="ms-2">  Resume</span>  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i><span class="ms-2">Portfolio</span> </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-server"></i><span class="ms-2">Services</span> </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> <span class="ms-2">Contact</span></a>
                  </li>
                     
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
     <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-9  hero_image">

     </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

At this Code snippet, you can see, that when it's reduced (right after running) you can see "large" sunset image; If you enlarge it (open in full screen), you will see sidebar.